# Apple Push Notifications to specific Users

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, push-notification

as far as I understand APN's I can only send them to the app not a specific user that uses my app.

Is there a way of sending APN's only to specific users that use my app? I can't think of a way of doing this...

Greetz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

APNS is not a broadcast medium. [As it says in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html):

> Apple Push Notification service transports and routes a notification
>   from a given provider to a given device.

When you send a notification from the server, one of the paramters is the device ID.

Comment: ok, I got this completely wrong. So all I have to do is group my users and then save device ID's to a database. This way I can send messages to usergroups

Answer (score 9):

Apple's Push Notifications are always sent to specific 'users' (a specific device being an iphone, ipad)

What you do when you want to use APN is register the application for push notifications. Then you get a token that links the user's device to the notification service. You then use this token to 'push notifications' to APN which will in turn send a notification to that device. Notifications are pushed by 'Providers'.

Here's apple's documentation on the matter: [Apple Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)

Look up 'Registering for Remote Notifications' to register the device
and 'Handling Local and Remote Notifications' to handle the incoming notifications.

Read up on how to send notifications here: [Providers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. I use Easy APNS and in `newMessage()` you can specify the PID (saved in a MySQL database) of the user.

Have a look at http://www.easyapns.com/